# How do I display the child elements in a WebComponent?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I'm trying to rebuild a React Component as a WebComponent to remove the dependency on React.

I'd like to have a WebComponent that looks like this in HTML:

```
<editable-h1>Hello, world</editable-h1>
```

It should render like this:

```
<span>
  <h1>Hello, world</h1>
  <button onClick=this.onEdit>Edit</button>
</span>
```

And if I click the edit button, I'd like to have it render like:

```
<form>
  <input type='text' value='Hello, world'></input>
  <button onClick=this.onSave>Save</button>
</form>
```

Clicking the save button saves the change to the database via an API call, and returns rendering to the original rendering (but with the edited text).

I'm confident I can handle switching renders and making the API calls, but what I'm confused about is how I can get the child element text "Hello, world" from the initial WebComponent in order to render it.

Answer (score 0):

The `connectedCallback` fires on the **opening tag** `<editable-h1>`

So your `Hello World` *innerHTML* has not been parsed yet

To wait till parsing has finished, use a `setTimeout`

Note: All tools and libraries that provide you with a `parsedCallback` will do a similar trick under the hood, with `requestAnimationFrame` or `MutationObserver` (and lots more lines of code).

If you think a one line `setTimeout` is a hack; or you do not want to loose that *one millisecond* with `setTimeout`, check out [Andrea Giammarchi his html-parsed-element code](https://github.com/WebReflection/html-parsed-element/blob/master/esm/index.js)
(which ofcourse takes time to load and parse. And adds a dependency and code complexity, so overall takes a **lot** more)

And follow the WC gurus, this discussion just goes on and on:
*Need a callback for when children changed or parser finished parsing children*
https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/809

**All approaches boil down to the same: *Wait till the EventLoop is empty***

What the f* is the Event Loop? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

```js
customElements.define("editable-h1", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.innerHTML = `<h1>${this.innerHTML}</h1><button>Edit</button>`;
      
      let h1     = this.querySelector("h1");
      let button = this.querySelector("button");
      
      button.onclick = (evt) => {
        button.innerHTML = (h1.contentEditable = !h1.isContentEditable) 
                              ? (h1.focus(),"Save")
                              : "Edit";
      }
      
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<editable-h1>Hello World!</editable-h1>

<editable-h1>Hello Web Components World!</editable-h1>
```